# Inequality regarding inner product and functions with zero integral

Tags: inequality, inner-products

Suppose $X$ is a finite set and $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $\sum_{x\in X}f(x)=0$. Let $p\in\Delta(X)$ be a probability measure on $X$. Does the following statement hold?
$$
\sum_{x\in X} f(x)(p(x))^2 \ge 0 \Rightarrow \sum_{x\in X} f(x)p(x) \ge 0.
$$

I find it hard to find any counterexamples. I know that when $|X|=2$ the statement holds. Also, Cauchy-Schwarts does not seem to lead me anywhere. I feel like some generalized version of Jensen's inequality could work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter-example: $X=\{-1,0,1\}, f(-1)=-1, f(0)=\frac 5 8, f(1)=\frac  3 8, p(-1)=\frac 1  3 , p(1)=0, p(1)=\frac 2  3$.

Comment: Thanks! I am quite stupid it seems.